# Why are git commands like push printing "\S Kernel on an" to the terminal each time i run them?

Tags: git, ssh, git-remote

When I run git, it is printing some odd text to the terminal that seems unrelated to the command. For example, with `git push`:

```
$ git push
\S
Kernel  on an 
Everything up-to-date
```

I've noticed it *only happens when my commands involve the remote repo.*

Is this a bug? Something I should worry about?

Here is some additional information about my environment:

```
$ echo $0 $SHELL
-zsh /bin/bash
```

```
$ git --version
git version 2.35.1
```

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

```
$ git remote -vv
origin  <redacted>:<redacted>.git (fetch)
origin  <redacted>:<redacted>.git (push)
```

```
$ git push --verbose
Pushing to <redacted>:<redacted>.git
\S
Kernel  on an 
To <redacted>:<redacted>.git
 = [up to date]      master -> master
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master'
Everything up-to-date
```

```
$ ls -1 .git/hooks
applypatch-msg.sample
commit-msg.sample
fsmonitor-watchman.sample
post-update.sample
pre-applypatch.sample
pre-commit.sample
pre-merge-commit.sample
pre-push.sample
pre-rebase.sample
pre-receive.sample
prepare-commit-msg.sample
push-to-checkout.sample
update.sample
```

```
$ cat .git/hooks/*push
zsh: no matches found: .git/hooks/*push
```

```
$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git

$ file /usr/local/bin/git
/usr/local/bin/git: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

Comment: Do you have any [git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) set up?

Comment: Need more details. Please update your question with the output of these commands: `echo $0 $SHELL`, `git --version`, `git status`, `git remote -vv`, `git push --verbose`, `ls .git/hooks`, `cat .git/hooks/*push`.

Comment: If you're pushing via ssh, also check what `ssh <host> echo test` says (with the appropriate machine inserted).

Comment: @Inigo Updated with requested outputs.

Comment: Is there a custom version of `git` on your `PATH`, or maybe `git` is a shell alias that does something special before calling the regular `git`?

Comment: @RaymondChen I updated the question with some additional output. That would not seem to be case.

Comment: Or any alias defined?

Comment: Everything looks kosher on your side, though I forgot to as you to provide `git config --get-regexp ^alias\.` But maybe that's not necessary. See my answer.

Comment: @Inigo `git config --get-regexp ^alias\.` gives no output.

Comment: @jessehouwing No aliases defined related to git.

Comment: Just to make sure it's not an alias or shell function, try `/usr/local/bin/git push`

Comment: I believe i figured it out. But please confirm: you are pushing over ssh?

Comment: @Inigo Yes, I am pushing over SSH.

Comment: @RaymondChen Still got the weird output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text

```
\S
Kernel  on an \S
```

is almost certainly the [ssh pre-login banner](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/issue.5.html) configured for the ssh daemon on the server you are pushing to. It is defined on the server in the [`/etc/issue`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84280/is-etc-issue-common-for-all-linux-distributions) file.

It appears to be misconfigured, as the login banner is probably intended to show something like:

```
Redhat blah blah blah
Kernel 2.6.11.12 on an i486
```

You can verify this by ssh'ing to the server directly, which is more or less what @torek suggested.